# How to remove http header from Response in WSO2 ESB

Tags: http, wso2, wso2-esb

I am getting certain http headers in my response. out of those I want to remove one Header 'Server' which is giving information of server which I am using.

```
Date    Fri, 09 Jan 2015 11:11:17 GMT
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
#status#    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type    text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Connection  Keep-Alive
Server  WSO2-PassThrough-HTTP
```

I have tried to put header mediator with action ='remove' but it is not removed.

please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

```
<property name="Server" action="remove" scope="transport"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jean-Michel. but I have already tried this but did not work for me. Can you please suggest in detail. may be I am making some mistake. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must add this property def just before send mediator in your outSequence. I've tried it with success using NIO http transport but never tried with PassThrough transport. To use NIO you just have to rename repository/conf/axis2_nhttp.xml to repository/conf/axis2.xml

Comment: Thanks to clarify. I tried it with  NIO http transport and worked for me.
But my problem is with PassThrough transport.I am not able to remove Server header with PassThrough transport.

Comment: Try to play with http.server.preserve property (set it to false) in repository/conf/passthru-http.properties

Answer (score 3):

You can use below,

```
    <property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
    <property action="remove" name="EXCESS_TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
```

This worked for me